# is Le creuset pan 22 cms enamelled or not

Tags: cookware, cast-iron

I bought an old pan on ebay and I wish to know if it is enamelled or raw. Inside of pan has a black layer and a spot patch 6 by 3 cms of different layernature.
How do I find out out if pan is raw cast iron. The thin black layer is difficult to identify. The seller says that pan is not enamelled. But I doubt it.

Comment: see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/48943/67

Answer (score 0):

Enamel is usually white, though it may stain to a beige color.

Bare cast iron when stripped of its seasoning is steel grey. The first coat of seasoning will be a dull olive greenish brown, and each coat of seasoning will get darker. With use the seasoning will turn jet black as some of the oil polymers get toasted more over time.

If it is bare cast iron you will want to continue to wipe it down with oil after each use at a bare minimum of care.

Comment: Enamel is whatever color the manufacturer colors it. Le Creuset likes strong primary colors for the outside, but their current line has a black pebbled enamel on the inside specifically created to mimic seasoned iron.

Comment: Le cruesset enamel's the inside white. I haven't seen the inside pebbles enamel line. The enameled le cruesset pieces I have are bare iron on the inside.

Comment: http://www.twopeasandtheirpod.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2_3-8qt_iron_h_skillet_caribbean_L2024_3017_full.jpg - that's the one I mean. It's enameled in color outside and in black inside.

Comment: Well now I am a little flabbergasted, I was going to take a picture of my skillet, which is also the same sky blue, but I can't find it (obviously I don't use it so much). Where the heck did it go?

Comment: If it is seasoned, a picture doesn't mean much. The finishing looks so close to seasoning, there is no way to distinguish them from a picture. Even in person, I would need to touch them and wouldn't be 100% sure even then.

Comment: Well right, that was my point actually.